# Gas central heating on max for hours. What are short and long term adverse effects other than higher bills?

Tags: heating, gas

I've had a new boiler fitted, a Bosch-Worcester one, in a medium size house. It's been serviced professionally, when required. The new boiler came with a thermostat control pad. All the copper piping for radiators was left as is. It's at least 20 years since these copper pipes were changed.

There is a person in my house, let's call her "the wife", who sets the pad at a high temperature then puts it in a room or area with no heating. This results in the constant burning of gas for hours on end (I'm out at work so don't know for how long exactly, "several to half dozen+ hours" is the best guess). Radiators are so hot, they cannot be touched for longer than a second or two. This is a several times a week occurrence and will be perpetrated until Spring.

Other than higher gas bills, what are the short and long term adverse effects on the central heating?

Comment: What control system do you have exactly?  Many such smart systems allow you to add fixed location thermostats as well as using a mobile one, to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: It's not a "smart" boiler or a "smart" thermostat pad. It's a wall-hanging one that doesn't hang on walls. It simply tells the boiler "temperature not achieved".

Comment: Ah.  A quick google of Bosch-Worcester showed that they make smart ones, so I assumed that was what you meant.  Still, if you give the model, there may be solutions.  If the system supports multiple thermostats at all, you may simply be able to add one that does hang on the wall as well.